# Do Actions in RCAV = Model in MVC? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm trying to better understand the Rails workflow, specifically RCAV in relation to MVC. I know that MVC is the typical structure of a Rails app and that RCAV is the standard order of building various components of the app, however, I'm a little confused about the correlation between the two.

For example, I'm assuming the routes in RCAV are what link the models with views and controller in MVC. Is this correct?

I'm also guessing that the controller and view in RCAV are the same as the controller and view in MVC and simply represent the order in which you build them. Is this correct as well?

What I'm really stuck on is the Action part of RCAV - does this represent the Model component of MVC?

Sorry if my question doesn't make sense, just trying to get a better hang of the standard Rails workflow and the order in which various components of an app are typically built. I wish it were a little more distilled i.e. "first build Model, then Views, then Controller" but this whole separate RCAV thing is confusing me a little.

Comment: I think the "CA" is one thing, "controller action." It refers to the methods in your controller that routes link to, generally `index`, `create`, `show`, etc.

Comment: Things can be built in any order, although without the route, controllers are harder to test. I don't see how an action could be thought to represent a model; a Rails controller implements actions, the *controller* in MVC is what determines what handles what requests (messages, calls, etc.)

Comment: My own take is that you're vastly over-complicating this.

Comment: Also, unless I'm mistaken "RCAV" refers to the order of execution when Rails receives a request. It does not refer to the order you should build thing in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your title question, **no.**

To elaborate, it's kind of confusing to map out RCAV (the sequence) against MVC (the framework), but I'll see if I can clarify. It's worth noting that the concepts themselves are not as complex as they seem, it's just confusing to explain.

**RCAV**
(Route-Controller-Action-View)

*Routes* are defined in config/routes.rb. You may think of them as the coupling between an HTTP Request and a Method (a specific type of method called an Action). On the one side it defines a path (ex. "/login") and one of the HTTP verbs (ex. "GET"), and says that whenever that type of request is made to that location, to perform the appropriate action. On the other side, an action is given in the form of the name of its controller (ex. "sessions"), and the name of the method itself (ex. "new").

*Controllers* receive the request according to the routes (so following the above example, if a user navigated to www.example.com/login, they would wind up in the sessions controller, which would be housed in app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb). The Controller may perform a number of functions prior to (and following) the action, in the form of callbacks. Callbacks are arguably a more advanced concept than what you need to understand right now, they are an important step (and the reason I explain RCAV as "Route >> Controller >> Action >> View", not as "Route >> Controller-Action >> View").

*Actions* are public methods in the Controller. Again, by our above example, you'll be hitting a method named "new" in the sessions_controller when a user navigates to www.example.com/login. Actions may perform any variety of functions, and there is often interaction with the model here (for instance, you may have a session model in app/models/sessions.rb with a method named "logout", and perhaps the first thing you do when you hit the login page is ensure the user is currently logged out by calling `Session.logout`. This is a poor design, but a decent example). Your action must "return" in one way or another. Assuming your action is meant to be consumed by a user directly through their browser (as opposed to as, say, a JSON or XML service), you will either render a view now, or redirect_to another action.

*Views* are, dare I say, the "end result" of the action. If nothing is specified, the above example will end by rendering "app/views/sessions/new.html.erb" for the user (Rails defaults to rendering the view whose path matches the controller and action, but as referenced above you could name something different). In this file you will also potentially make reference to the model associated with sessions (but this time inside of ERB tags, to be compiled into HTML).

**MVC**
(Model-View-Controller)

*Models* are classes tied, generally, to tables in a database. They contain validations for their fields, class methods, and instance methods. Say your database keeps track of sessions. Then you could potentially grab a list of sessions by calling `Session.all` anywhere in your application. You'd probably use an action in the Sessions controller to save this list to an instance variable (maybe `@sessions`), which could in turn be accessed in its appropriate view (`<% @sessions.each do |s| %> ... <% end %>`).

*Views* are essentially the web pages. They can bring along their own styles and scripts, and exist in the form of HTML files with embedded ruby. They are the end point of request made to your site (unless you're hitting a service which returns something like JSON or XML instead).

*Controllers* contain all the actions a user may access, often prepare variables via methods from the models, and generally drop the user into a view.

**In Summation**

A user accesses a route. The route drops them into a specific action within a controller. The controller (in the form of callbacks) and the action (on its own) prepare data from the model (via instance variables) to be consumed by the view. The view is then rendered into the users browser.

This *is* a simplification, but in the most standard cases, this is how the MVC framework (and rails, specifically) functions.